# Similarity Of Matrices

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, randomness

Give a randomized algorithm that takes input two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with integer
entries and does the following: If $A$ and $B$ are similar, then with high probability the algorithm outputs
an $n \times n$ invertible matrix $C$ with rational entries such that $CAC^{−1} = B$; otherwise it outputs $A$ not
similar to $B$. Ensure that your algorithm runs in polynomial time.

Comment: Interesting question! What are your thoughts on it? Why have you tried? We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: Oh ok so I was wondering that to check the similarity of the matrices we can compare the Jodan Canonical Form of the two matrices, but I cannot figure out how to do that or even if we could do that how to proceed towards calculating $C$. A hint in the correct direction would be helpful.

Comment: You can compute the Jordan form together with the base change matrix, from which you can easily compute $C$. But I suspect that the question is asking for a different solution. I'm not sure what kind of solution, though.

Comment: How efficiently can we compute the Jordan form or the base change matrix? Yes I also think the question demands a different approach

Comment: After calculating the eigenvalues (say via diagonalization), you can determine the size of the blocks by computing ranks of powers of $A-\lambda$ for the various eigenvalues $\lambda$.

Comment: The Jordan canonical form takes you to work with complex numbers and approximate roots. As a consequence the $C$ you get from it might not have rational entries. Instead, it is better to use the [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form)

Comment: Here is a hint: try to find a reduction from this problem to polynomial identity testing, for which the Schwartz-Zippel Lemma provides a randomized algorithm.

Comment: @MassimoCafaro I see how to test using the lemma, but the problem also requires computing $C$. Can the computation of $C$ be reduced in polynomial time to the decision problem of polynomial identity?

Comment: Think about the entries of $C$ as being variables. Then, $CAC^-1 - B = 0$ with $0$ the null matrix is a system of homogeneous equations. Now, to reconstruct $C$ apply Schwartz-Zippel for polynomial identity testing.

Comment: @MassimoCafaro Polynomial identity testing (PIT) tells when a polynomial is identically zero. It wouldn't give a solution of a polynomial equation like $CAC^{-1}-B=0$, or, like we need, a solution such that $C$ is invertible. Similarity of $A$ and $B$ is equivalent to the polynomial matrices $A-xI$ and $B-xI$ having the same collection of *invariant factors*, which are polynomials. Testing this equality of invariant factors can be done with Schwartz-Zippel. A $C$ can be found in many ways, but I don't see how Schwartz-Zippel can help to do it.

Comment: The problem's requirement seems strange to me. It seems to me that one can just compute the Frobenius normal form for each matrix $A$ and $B$ in polynomial time and that gives you both a test for similarity and the matrix $C$ with entries in the same field as the entries of $A$ and $B$ (in this case the rational numbers). I guess one could consider this deterministic algorithm as trivially randomized, but what is the point of the requirement then?

Answer (score 3):

I don't get very well the point of the requirement in the problem of a randomized algorithm. Or maybe I am misinterpreting what is the notion of problem size with respect to which the running time is required to be polynomially bounded. With respect to the number of entries of $A$ and $B$ there is the following deterministic algorithm.

The requirement of $C$ having rational entries, or more generally entries in the same field as the entries of $A$ and $B$ points to using the [Frobenius/Rational normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) (FNF). The [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) is inconvenient because, in general, it requires working in a field extension in which the characteristic polynomials of $A$ and $B$ factor completely (split).

Just like in the case of Jordan normal form, there are invertible matrices $P_1,P_2$ such that $P_1AP_1^{-1}=A_f$ and $P_2BP_2^{-1}=B_f$ and $A_f, B_f$ are the Frobenius normal forms of $A,B$, respectively. The additional property that we mentioned before is that all these matrices have entries in the same field as the entries of $A$ and $B$.So, if your matrices have integer entries, then these matrices will have rational entries.

Now, the matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if $A_f=B_f$. When this happens we can compute the required $C$ from $P_1AP_1^{-1}=A_f=B_f=P_2BP_2^{-1}$, since we get $(P_2^{-1}P_1)A(P_2^{-1}P_1)^{-1}=B$. So, we can take $C=P_2^{-1}P_1$.

The FNF can be computed (without emphasis on efficiency) by considering the polynomial matrices $A-xI$ and $B-xI$ and reducing them to their [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). This consists in a combination of Gauss elimination (row/column reduction, if you call it that way) combined with Euclid algorithm to compute some polynomial GCDs that are required. The Smith normal form tells you the *invariant factors*, and then the Frobenius normal form is the block-diagonal matrix in which the blocks are the [companion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the invariant factors. The sequence of steps to reduce $A-xI$ and $B-xI$ to their Smith normal forms give you the $P_1$ and $P_2$ required above.

Justifying all these claims requires a long exposition of the linear algebra (and either explicitly or implicitly the [structure theorem of finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain)). This can be found in many linear algebra books. One that I know has it is Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*.

---

A guess of how randomization could be used is by trying random vectors $v$ and finding the maximal [Krylov subspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace) that it generates. This is, the space generated by $v,Av,A^2v,A^3v,...$, which ought to be generated by finitely many of those vectors. Each one of those give you a cyclic invariant subspace of $A$, which tell you a block of the Frobenius normal form. Then pass to the quotient space by this subspace and repeat until you find all blocks of the FNF. Understanding the theory is required again to see why.